# Divide a data frame with same data frame (sliced) in panda's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the data frame 
df =

```
     a    b     c
0  1.0  4.0   5.0
1  3.0  8.0  45.0
2  5.0  3.0  67.0
3  2.0  7.0  34.0
```

I'd want to now divide the dataframe df's 2nd and 3rd rows with the 0th and 1st rows of df i.e I'd want to divide i th row with i-k th row. The expected result should be

```
     a    b     c
0  Nan  Nan   Nan
1  Nan  Nan Nan
2  5.0/1  3.0/4  67/5
3  2/3  7/8  34/45
```

As a simple formula it is (price[t]/price[t-N]) if price is assumed to be dataframe and t are the rows.
Is there a simple way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps an example output?

Comment: Added few more details. Please let me know if it is making sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
print (df.shift(2))
     a    b     c
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  1.0  4.0   5.0
3  3.0  8.0  45.0

print (df.div(df.shift(2)))
         a      b          c
0       NaN    NaN        NaN
1       NaN    NaN        NaN
2  5.000000  0.750  13.400000
3  0.666667  0.875   0.755556
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple.